# Expeced positional parameter count 4

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate named query and  i am facing the issue  Expected positional parameter count.
i am  giving the query

```
<query><![CDATA[

 SELECT
 UCN.UCN_FIRST_NAME                         "FIRST NAME"
 ,UCN.UCN_LAST_NAME                          "LAST NAME"
 ,UCN.UCN_EMAIL_ID                           "E-MAIL ID"
,UCN.UCN_PEOPLESOFT_ID                      "PEOPLE SOFT ID"
,UCN.UCN_USER_ID                            "LAN ID"
,DECODE(UCN.UCN_LOCKED_IND
 ,'Y','Yes'
 ,'N','No'
 ,NULL
 )                                          "IS THE USER LOCKED?"
  ,(SELECT
 LISTAGG(LAS1.LAS_CONTEXT_LOCALE_NAME,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY    URL.UCN_ID)
 FROM
 ET2_OWNER.USER_ROLE URL
 ,ET2_OWNER.LANGUAGE_ASSOCIATION LAS1
 WHERE UCN.UCN_ID = URL.UCN_ID
 AND LAS1.LAS_CONTEXT_ID = URL.ARL_ID
 AND LAS1.LAN_ID = :LAN_ID
 AND LAS1.CON_ID = :CON_ID
 AND LAS1.LAS_CONTEXT_CODE = :LAS_CONTEXT_CODE
 GROUP BY URL.UCN_ID
)                                            "NON-PRODUCT SPECIFIC ROLE"
,DECODE(UCN.UCN_PROXY_USER_IND
     ,'Y','Yes'
     ,'N','No'
     ,NULL
     )                                    "HAS PROXY USER PRIVILEGE?"
 ,DECODE(UCN.UCN_CAN_TRANSACT_CST
     ,'Y','Yes'
     ,'N','No'
     ,NULL
     )                                    "TRANSACT WITHOUT CST?"
  ,DECODE(UCN.UCN_REVIEWER_FLAG
     ,'Y','Yes'
     ,'N','No'
     ,NULL
     )                                    "IS A PEER REVIEWER?"
 ,(SELECT
 LISTAGG(PRD.PRD_PRODUCT_CODE
         ||' --> '||DECODE(UPT.UPT_COMP_LEVEL
                    ,'H','High'
                    ,'L','Low'
                    ,UPT.UPT_COMP_LEVEL
                  )
          ||' --> '||LAS.LAS_CONTEXT_LOCALE_NAME,', '||CHR(13))
 WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PRD.PRD_PRODUCT_CODE)
  FROM
  ET2_OWNER.USER_PRODUCT UPT
 ,ET2_OWNER.LANGUAGE_ASSOCIATION LAS
 ,ET2_OWNER.PRODUCT PRD
  WHERE UCN.UCN_ID = UPT.UCN_ID
 AND LAS.LAS_CONTEXT_ID = UPT.ARL_ID
 AND PRD.PRD_ID = UPT.PRD_ID
 AND LAS.LAN_ID = :LAN_ID
 AND LAS.CON_ID = :CON_ID
 AND LAS.LAS_CONTEXT_CODE = :LAS_CONTEXT_CODE
  GROUP BY UPT.UCN_ID
 )                                             PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_ROLE
 ,PRC.PCT_PRACTICE_NAME                        PRACTICE
 ,REG.RGN_REGION_NAME                          REGION
 ,OFF.OFF_OFFICE_NAME                          OFFICE
 ,UCN.UCN_LAND_PHONE_NUMBER                   "PHONE NUMBER"
 ,'ENGLISH-GREAT BRITAIN'                     "LANGUAGE"
FROM
  ET2_OWNER.USER_CONTACT UCN
 ,ET2_OWNER.USER_OFFICE UOF
 ,ET2_OWNER.OFFICE OFF
 ,ET2_OWNER.REGION REG
 ,ET2_OWNER.PRACTICE PRC
WHERE UCN.UCN_USER_TYPE = :UCN_USER_TYPE
AND UCN.UCN_STATUS = :UCN_STATUS
  AND UCN.UCN_ID = UOF.UCN_ID
 AND UOF.OFF_ID = OFF.OFF_ID
  AND OFF.RGN_ID = REG.RGN_ID
  --AND REG.RGN_REGION_NAME in ('Central','South')
 AND UCN.UCN_EMAIL_ID NOT IN ( 'abc"gmail.com','cba@gmail.com','b@gmail.com'
                            ,
                                                                ,'ji.f@yahoo.com'
                                                              )
                                )
 ]]></query>
```

This  is my query and i am  using this code for the the data population

```
Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(QueryNames.FIND_ACTIVE_MARSH_USER.value());
    query.setParameter("LAN_ID", "en-gb");
    query.setParameter("CON_ID", "GB");
    query.setParameter("LAS_CONTEXT_CODE", "ARL");
    query.setParameter("UCN_USER_TYPE", "M");
```

Getting this exception

```
Expanded non LONG bind data supplied after actual LONG or LOB column.
```

Answer (score 0):

:UCN_STATUS parameter is not bound.

Agreed, the error message is not clear, but this is the message you'll get either when the parameter is not bound, or when it is bound with `null`